# How many combinations of passwords can be created according to these conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose that a password must have at least $8$, but not more than $10$ characters, where each character in the password is either *one of the $26$ lower case English letters*, or *one of the $10$ digits*, or *one of the $6$ special characters $∗, \gt, \lt, !, +, =$*.
>
> $(i)$ How many different passwords are there?
>
> $(ii)$ How many of these passwords contain at least one occurrence of at least
>       one of the special characters?

For part $(i)$, I think it's a total of $42$ characters therefore $42\choose10$ (no. of $10$ character passwords) minus $42\choose8$ (no. of $8$ character passwords)   .
For part $(ii)$, I've no idea.

I'd appreciate a bit of guidance.

Comment: Apologies, I shall rephrase

Comment: Must the passwords have all distinct characters?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I don't think so, the question isn't clear about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) $42^8+42^9+42^{10}$

ii)$[42^8+42^9+42^{10}]-[36^8+36^9+36^{10}]$  (The total number of possible password minus those that contains none of the special characters)

Comment: let A be the set of all the password, let B be the set of all the password that contains at least one special character.  Then $ B=A-B^c$

Comment: If you wanted to select the no. of ways you can choose 8 characters from 42, would it not be 42C8? And therefore the answer be 42C8+42C9+42C10?

Comment: The order matters here, and it is with repetition.

Comment: When you say 42C8, you are assuming that the order doesn't matter, and it is without repetition.

Comment: Ah okay, I get why repetition would be allowed, but surely the order of the characters in the password wouldn't?

Comment: is the password 123 same as the password 321?

Comment: No, it isn't, you're right. Thanks for your help